# warning: passing argument 2 of ‘accept’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]

Tags: c, tcp, client-server, tcplistener

I get the warning: passing argument 2 of ‘accept’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]

Why am I getting this error?

```
        if(s = accept(ls, &client_address, &client_address_len)<0);
        {
            perror("Error: accepting failed!!");
            exit(1);
        }
```

Comment: How is `client_address` defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/accept.html, the second argument of `accept` function receives a type of `struct sockaddr *`. You might want to do a conversion: `&client_address` to `(struct sockaddr *)&client_address`